# Поиск по буквам или части слова

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте. Создал хранимую процедуру с одним параметром,

```
declare @sch text
select name, summ, time from order
where name like @sch
```

В visual studio накидал форму, в `datagrid` вывел таблицу, вставил элемент `textbox` (в него ввожу параметры поиска), поиск по целому слову получается, а как сделать, чтобы поиск шел по буквам или части слова?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте документацию по оператору [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179859.aspx). Он позволяет выполнять поиск не по заданной строке (для этого и хватило бы оператора **'='**), а по шаблону строки. Обратите внимание на символ-шаблон **'%'** это то, что вам нужно.

---

Код для конкретно вашей задачи:

```
select name, summ, time
from order
where name like '%' + @sch + '%'
```